# Cannot find ContentPlaceHolder 'MainContent' in the master page '/Site.master',

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to communicate with the other pages from masterpage but I think something is wrong. I am getting an error after I jump on the page

Master page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
       <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity"sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light " style="background-color:#aea5f7">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
    <a class="navbar-brand text-white" href="#">Hidden brand</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0 ">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">About Us <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled text-white" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="form-inline navbar-nav  my-2 my-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-white" href='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/login.aspx") %>'>Login</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-white " href='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/registartion.aspx") %>'>SignUp</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Child page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="login.aspx.cs" Inherits="loginRegistration.login" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
<div class="col-lg-6">
<h1>LogIn</h1>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    Name
    <asp:TextBox ID="name" class="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
     Email
    <asp:TextBox ID="email" class="form-control" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" Text="Save"  />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2"  runat="server"  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" Text="Update"  />
    <asp:Label ID="saved" runat="server"></asp:Label>


    </form>

    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

```
Cannot find ContentPlaceHolder 'MainContent' in the master page '/Site.master', verify content control's ContentPlaceHolderID attribute in the content page
[HttpException (0x80004005): Cannot find ContentPlaceHolder 'MainContent' in the master page '/Site.master', verify content control's ContentPlaceHolderID attribute in the content page.]
   System.Web.UI.MasterPage.CreateMaster(TemplateControl owner, HttpContext context, VirtualPath masterPageFile, IDictionary contentTemplateCollection) +1458
   System.Web.UI.Page.get_Master() +116
   System.Web.UI.Page.ApplyMasterPage() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit() +83
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1910
```

Comment: Hmm everything seems to be in order, are you sure you are using the right masterpage? The page is using Site.Master, is that the file where you got the code you pasted here?

Comment: Yes when i run the master page then it makes problem

Comment: ok now i get it this code is fine and it is in working condition